# based on object value how do i get NSMutableArray index value

Tags: iphone

How do i get index value from NSMutableArray.

I got `NSString *stringValue=@"e";`

And my `NSMutableArray *arrayValue=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`

```
[arrayValue addobject:@"a"];
[arrayValue addobject:@"b"];
[arrayValue addobject:@"c"];
[arrayValue addobject:@"d"];
[arrayValue addobject:@"e"];
[arrayValue addobject:@"f"];
[arrayValue addobject:@"g"];
```

I want to get array index value based on string value.

How to do

@thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wow, a quick look at the documentation ?

```
NSUInteger index = [ar indexOfObject:@"e"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `NSMutableArray` is a `NSArray` subclass, all the methods are also inherited. You're looking for the `indexOfObject:` function